# JQuery UI tooltips and dialog behavior

Tags: jquery-ui

I've a strange problem when I use Jquery UI tooltip with a popup (alert or dialog box).
When I click the button (where is defined a tooltip) for show a dialog/alert popup, when I close the alert box I see the tooltips message of the button and I have to click out for hide the tooltips.

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="ttip" value="Save" title="Click me to save !">
<br /><br />
<input type="button" class="ttip" value="Delete" title="Click me to delete">
```

JS

```
$( ".ttip" ).click(function() {
   alert("Some text");
});

$('.ttip').tooltip();
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hrrVK/10/)

How can I solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually removing the tooltip seems to work:

```
$( ".ttip" ).click(function() {
    alert("Some text");
    $('.ttip').tooltip( "close" );
});

$('.ttip').tooltip();
```